# How does gcc determine -march=native on x86? On arm?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, arm

I know that it's generally recommended to use -march=native (if you're compiling for the machine you're on), so that gcc determines your arch and cputype and generates the most machine-specific code, but how does it do that?

Does it use cpuid (on either arm or x86)? What techniques are used on platforms without a cpuid-like instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

My intuition was that it would go check `/proc/cpuinfo`. Actually it depends on the architecture it has been compiled to run on. It seems like `host_detect_local_cpu` is the function responsible for that. Its job is to replace `-march=native` by either the good `-march=<...>` or a set of flags (`-mmmx`, `-mno-avx`, etc) that match as closely as possible the current cpu. Examples for [`i386`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/95d162498f763e8780f188459d878476a6c52aeb/gcc/config/i386/driver-i386.c#L370-L1177) and [`arm`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/95d162498f763e8780f188459d878476a6c52aeb/gcc/config/arm/driver-arm.c#L43-L131). `i386` uses `cpuid` directly to check for each and every possible feature. `arm` checks in `/proc/cpuinfo` for the `CPU part` line and has a table that maps from a CPU part value to a generation of the architecture and use this directly in `-march=<...>`.

Just for fun I check on other architectures (I am not familiar with them).

- solaris on `sparc`: uses the `kstat` interface
- linux on `sparc`: uses `/proc/cpuinfo`
- `alpha`: uses the `implver` instruction
- darwin on `rs6000`: uses the `hw.cpusubtype` system call
- freebsd on `rs6000`: uses hardcoded `powerpc`
- linux on `rs6000`: checks in `/proc/self/auxv` for the platform value in the elf interpreter of its own process
- aix on `rs6000`: uses `_system_configuration` (apparently a global structure)